# PowerBuilder 11.5 on Windows 7 - Database profiles not visible

Tags: powerbuilder

After I installed PB 11.5 on Windows 7, I am not able to see list of database vendors (Oracle, SQL Server, etc.) in the "Database Profiles" screen.  Only the ODBC connection is visible. Is this related to security settings on laptop that prevented the correct install for PB?  I also installed PB 10.5 on the same machine and it works fine.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually related to which database drivers were installed. Maybe an uninstall/reinstall with a careful review of the database drivers selected would solve the problem.

The other potential problem is that you don't have PowerBuilder Enterprise, but you have Professional or Desktop instead. You'd have to contact Sybase about buying an upgrade if that is your problem.

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: Terry is correct, when you installed PB you would have had the option to choose database drivers.  I've had problems with prior versions of PB where for I had to run the PB installation again after installing Oracle client on the PC. You can look in your PB shared folder and tell which databases were installed, PBOR*.dll = oracle native, PBSY*.dll = sybase, etc.

Comment: If you think you did install the driver, check to make sure that the client dbms software (e.g. Oracle Client, Sybase CT/DB lib) as it is possible PB might not show them in the list without the proper client software installed...

Comment: I had all the pb native interfaces installed and working nicely in the trial version, BUT after I applied the license provided to me, they all disappeared from the database painter and only the ODBC interface remained.I saw the keyword PB_DESKTOP in the text of the license, which was incorrect. Getting the correct license solved the problem and my native interfaces came back.